# Row dissapears when checkbox in header is checked in Datatables

Tags: jquery, checkbox, datatables

I'm using jquery Datatables and have a problem: when I'm checking checkbox in header, rows below disappears and I receive "No matching records found" message. There are no js functions attached to this checkbox. I've tried to create checkbox in html, then I've tried to declare it in jquery:

```
"aoColumnDefs": [ { "sTitle": "<input type='checkbox' id='APP_CHECK_ALL'></input>","aTargets": [0] }]
```

both variants are not working. Did anybody have this problem?

Comment: There must be a js event handler attached, as it's obviously redrawing the datatable

Comment: The information provided with the question is too sparse to figure out what the problem is.